# PHP version upgrade

Tags: linux, php

I am using Linux mint. I am trying to upgrade my php version from 7.3 to 7.4. I used below commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.4



sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-cli php7.4-bcmath php7.4-bz2 php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-intl php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-readline php7.4-xml php7.4-zip php7.4-fpm


sudo a2dismod php7.3

sudo a2enmod php7.4

sudo service apache2 restart
```

But I am not getting php 7.4 in Terminal

[image]
[image]

Comment: You clearly have multiple versions of PHP installed.  You likely just have to update your PATH variable to point to the correct version of PHP. You can find the correct path in your Apache configuration file.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. Could you please explain more ? Where can I find Apache configuration file ?

Answer (score 1):

On the web server I looked at, /usr/bin/php is a symlink to /etc/alternatives/php, which in turn is a symlink to /usr/bin/php7.3

Typing

```
  update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

Changes this to 7.4  (You need to run this with sudo or as root)

Comment: Thanks @davidgo. In `/usr/bin` folder I can find this.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxT3X.png. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Thats what id expect to see. Did you try the solution I outlined above?

Comment: Thanks @davidgo. I am trying to open those files. But those files are not opening. Thanks.

Comment: What has opening those files got to do with anything?  You need to open a terminal window and type "sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4" in it.  That will fix your problem.